# Doing DOM Node-to-String transformation, but with namespace issues

Tags: java, xml

So we have an XML Document with custom namespaces.  (The XML is generated by software we don't control.  It's parsed by a namespace-*unaware* DOM parser; standard Java7SE/Xerces stuff, but also outside our effective control.)  The input data looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<MainTag xmlns="http://BlahBlahBlah" xmlns:CustomAttr="http://BlitherBlither">
    .... 18 blarzillion lines of XML ....
    <Thing CustomAttr:gibberish="borkborkbork" ... />
    .... another 27 blarzillion lines ....
</MainTag>
```

The Document we get is usable and xpath-queryable and traversable and so on.

Converting this Document into a text format for writing out to a data sink uses the standard Transformer approach described in a hundred SO "how do I change my XML Document into a Java string?" questions:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter();
transformer.transform (new DOMSource(theXMLDocument), new StreamResult(stringwriter));
return stringwriter.toString();
```

and it works perfectly.

But now I'd like to transform individual arbitrary Nodes from that Document into strings.  A `DOMSource` constructor accepts Node pointers just the same as it accepts a `Document` (and in fact Document is just a subclass of Node, so it's the same API as far as I can tell).  So passing in an individual Node in the place of "theXMLDocument" in the snippet above works great... until we get to the `Thing`.

At that point, `transform()` throws an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Namespace for prefix 'CustomAttr' has not been declared.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.SerializerBase.getNamespaceURI(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.SerializerBase.addAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToUnknownStream.addAttribute(Unknown Source)
    ......
```

That makes sense.  (The "com.sun.org.apache" is weird to read, but whatever.)  It makes sense, because the namespace for the custom attribute was declared at the root node, but now the transformer is starting at a child node and can't see the declarations "above" it in the tree.  So I think I understand the problem, or at least the symptom, but I'm not sure how to solve it though.

- If this were a String-to-Document conversion, we'd be using a `DocumentBuilderFactory` instance and could call `.setNamespaceAware(false)`, but this is going in the other direction.
- None of the available properties for `transformer.setOutputProperty()` affect the namespaceURI lookup, which makes sense.
- There is no such corresponding `setInputProperty` or similar function.
- The input parser wasn't namespace aware, which is how the "upstream" code got as far as creating its Document to hand to us.  I don't know how to hand that particular status flag on to the transforming code, which is what I really would like to do, I think.
- I *believe* it's possible to (somehow) add a `xmlns:CustomAttr="http://BlitherBlither"` attribute to the Thing node, the same as the root MainTag had.  But at that point the output is no longer identical XML to what was read in, even if it "means" the same thing, and the text strings are eventually going to be compared in the future.  We wouldn't know if it were needed until the exception got thrown, then we could add it and try again... ick.  For that matter, changing the Node would alter the original Document, and this really ought to be a read-only operation.

Advice?  Is there some way of telling the Transformer, "look, don't stress your dimwitted little head over whether the output is legit XML in isolation, it's not going to be parsed back in on its own (but you don't know that), just produce the text and let us worry about its context"?

Comment: You haven't shown the XSL you input to the transform that fails.  Is there any reason you can't make the XSL work from the document root instead of having to pass it a naked `Thing` node?

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm not knowledgeable enough about XML to understand your question, but I can state for a fact that we don't have any XSL involved; the code is just what I've shown above.  All we want is a plain text output.

Comment: This is not making sense to me. The CustomAttr namespace prefix is not even being used in the CustomAttr attribute. The attribute happens to have a name that is also in use as a namespace prefix, but this not relevant. Can you please show us the rest of the Thing?

Comment: @flup: Fixed, I believe, from what I've extracted out of the data.  (I don't know XML well enough to pick up on these things out of habit, sorry.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given your quoted error message "Namespace for prefix 'CustomAttr' has not been declared.",
I'm assuming that your pseudo code is along the lines of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<MainTag xmlns="http://BlahBlahBlah" xmlns:CustomAttr="http://BlitherBlither">
    .... 18 blarzillion lines of XML ....
    <Thing CustomAttr:attributeName="borkborkbork" ... />
    .... another 27 blarzillion lines ....
</MainTag>
```

With that assumption, here's my suggestion:
So you want to extract the "Thing" node from the "big" XML. The standard approach is to use a little XSLT to do that. You prepare the XSL transformation with:

```
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File("isolate-the-thing-node.xslt")));
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
transformer.setParameter("elementName", stringWithCurrentThing);    // parameterize transformation for each Thing
...
```

***EDIT***: @Ti, please note the parameterization instruction above (and below in the xslt).

The file 'isolate-the-thing-node.xslt' could be a flavour of the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:custom0="http://BlahBlahBlah"
    xmlns:custom1="http://BlitherBlither"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:param name="elementName">to-be-parameterized</xsl:param>
    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" />

    <xsl:template match="/*" priority="2" >
            <!--<xsl:apply-templates select="//custom0:Thing" />-->
            <!-- changed to parameterized selection: -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="custom0:*[local-name()=$elementName]" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*" priority="1">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hope that gets you over the "Thing" thing :)

Comment: As for using an XSLT transform like that, thanks, I'll look into it.  We've got to do this Node-to-text transformation several hundred thousand times on different element tags (the `Thing` above), so I would need to find some way of generating a new _select="//somepathhere:Thing"_ and inserting it into the input stream each time.  That's not difficult to do (ByteBrrayInputStream etc), but it would be slow.  Thanks again for the tip!

Comment: @TiStrga, regarding
*"We've got to do this Node-to-text transformation hundred thousand times..."*, I've edited the answer so it contains instructions on how to do a *parameterized* transformation - so you'll be able to pass the other "Things" into the xslt as 'elementName' parameters

Comment: I've marked this as the answer since it seems to be the best solution.  I haven't actually gotten anything running; the Java Transformer constructor fails with a "could not compile stylesheet" exception, giving the wonderfully useless text `ERROR:  'Syntax error in ''.'` (no line numbers or other helpful pointer, just "game over, go away").  We'll keep trying.  Thank you for the starting points!

Comment: hi @TiStrga, to troubleshoot your latest issue I suggest checking the xslt for validity. Use an external XML tool to do that (e.g.  XMLSpy). Also, to be on the safe side, add the XML declaration (<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>) as the first line, maybe the Java class that you're using choked because of that.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to parse the provided document, get the **Thing** node and print it without issues.

Take a look at the [Working Example](http://ideone.com/jFNe1P):

```
Node rootElement = d.getDocumentElement();
System.out.println("Whole document: \n");  
System.out.println(nodeToString(rootElement));
Node thing = rootElement.getChildNodes().item(1);
System.out.println("Just Thing: \n");  
System.out.println(nodeToString(thing));
```

**nodeToString**:

```
private static String nodeToString(Node node) {
  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
  try {
    Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
    t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    t.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(sw));
  } catch (TransformerException te) {
    System.out.println("nodeToString Transformer Exception");
  }
  return sw.toString();
}
```

**Output**:

```
Whole document: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><MainTag xmlns="http://BlahBlahBlah" xmlns:CustomAttr="http://BlitherBlither">
    <Thing CustomAttr="borkborkbork"/>
</MainTag>

Just Thing: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Thing CustomAttr="borkborkbork"/>
```

When I try the same code with `CustomAttr:attributeName` as suggested by @marty it fails with the original exception, so it looks like somewhere in your original XML you are prefixing a attribute or node with that custom `CustomAttr` namespace.

In the latter case you can leverage the problem with `setNamespaceAware(true)`, which will include the namespace information on the **Thing** node itself.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Thing xmlns:CustomAttr="http://BlitherBlither" CustomAttr:attributeName="borkborkbork" xmlns="http://BlahBlahBlah"/>
```